# XSLT: Howto exclude elements with a specific string

Tags: xslt

I have this xml:

```html
<Elements>
  <tag1>
    <ID>title</ID>
    <EventDescription>description</EventDescription>
    <ContentDuration>01:30:35:02</ContentDuration>
    <Format>format</Format>
    <Segment1>10:00:00:00-10:10:46:02</Segment1>
    <Segment2>10:10:46:08-10:22:31:13</Segment2>
    <Segment3>-</Segment3>
    <Segment4>-</Segment4>
    <Segment5>-</Segment5>
    <Segment6>-</Segment6>
  </tag1>
</Elements>
```

I would like to exclude element containing only the string "-"
the result should be like this

```html
<Elements>
<tag1>
 <ID>title</ID>
 <EventDescription>description</EventDescription>
 <ContentDuration>01:30:35:02</ContentDuration>
 <Format>format</Format>
 <Segment1>10:00:00:00-10:10:46:02</Segment1>
 <Segment2>10:10:46:08-10:22:31:13</Segment2>
 </tag1>
 </Elements>
```

Answer (score 2):

Start off with the [identity template.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Then add a template to match, and exclude, the elements that have text equals "-"

```
 <xsl:template match="*[text() = '-']" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="*[text() = '-']" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In response to LarsH's comment, if you did have a node like `<Segment3>-<a /></Segment3>` that you didn't want removed, try changing the template to this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and text() = '-']" />
```

Comment: This will exclude elements that have a text child node containing exactly `-`, which is consistent with the OP's title. But it will not only exclude 'element containing only the string "-"', because it would also exclude elements that have element children and other text children (alongside `-`). E.g. this will exclude `<a>-<b />foo</a>`, which may not be what the OP intends.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: That would mostly fix it, although `not(*)` only says that there are no child *elements*. In theory you could have multiple child nodes even without child elements. E.g. a comment or PI: `<Segment3>-<!-- Wow. -->Important data</Segment3>` would get deleted. You could use a match pattern like `match="*[text() = '-' and count(child::node()) = 1]`.